# Rails 3: How to validate on create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I try to use this line of code to do validate but it does not work, the method of must_agree does not apply to any method.

`validate :must_agree_to_terms, :on => :create`

Comment: I assume you mean "the method of `must_agree_to_terms` does not apply to any method"?  And by "any method" you mean any controller action, including `create`?

Comment: create is not a controller action, it's the ActiveRecord `.create()` call. What do your automated tests say when you call `MyModel.create(:must_agree_to_terms => true)`, compared to `MyModel.create(:must_agree_to_terms => nil)`?

Comment: Good call @Phlip - I totally misread the question. :)